# Android BaseAdapter getView

Tags: android, gridview

I found GridView guide on developer android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

"At the end of the getView() method, the position integer passed into the method is used to select an image from the mThumbIds array, which is set as the image resource for the ImageView."

I'm confused about this.

Why do we need to call setImageResource every time instead of calling it only if convertView is null? Shouldn't convertView if it is not null already have image resource set, like with padding, scale settings, etc.

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check this sentence from the [Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html):

> `getView()` This method creates a new View for each image added to the ImageAdapter. When this is called, a View is passed in, which is normally a recycled object (at least after this has been called once).

So if the system recycle a view, *it will recycle as in the state they were left*. So If image was set to an `ImageView` when leaving the screen, it will be there when the system re-uses it (the `convertView`) so it must be explicitly reinitialized. Though `padding`, `scale` won't affect as there used to be the same for all `imageview`s, but ImageResource needs to be set everytime.

Answer (score 1):

for each position the image resource is different and that's why we need to call setImageResource

if convertView != null that means a previously instance view is being used which has image resource of older position